# Phantom ForeignKey to similar model representing a DB view

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to get this 'phantom' ForeignKey to reference a model that is a view on the backend.  The view assembles data that includes some data from the originating table(so they share a primary key).

Here's a simplified version of what we've had to setup(view is more complex than just the model, so it was chosen to design it this way).

```
class VSpouse(models.Model):
    person_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    ...

class Person(models.Model):
    person_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    spouse = models.ForeignKey(VSpouse, db_column = 'person_id', to_field='person_id', null=True)
    ...
```

Now, since the tables were designed on the backend before models, we have never used `syncdb`.  Because of that, we've never noticed a problem and things work just as expected.

However, now we're starting to develop some Django tests, and when it begins to build the test DB, we see the following:

```
$ python2 manage.py test misc --traceback
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
Destroying old test database 'default'...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 222, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 72, in execute
    super(Command, self).execute(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 255, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 89, in handle
    failures = test_runner.run_tests(test_labels)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/simple.py", line 367, in run_tests
    old_config = self.setup_databases()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/simple.py", line 315, in setup_databases
    self.verbosity, autoclobber=not self.interactive)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/creation.py", line 293, in create_test_db
    load_initial_data=False)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 161, in call_command
    return klass.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 255, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 385, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 102, in handle_noargs
    cursor.execute(statement)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 58, in execute
    six.reraise(utils.DatabaseError, utils.DatabaseError(*tuple(e.args)), sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 54, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
DatabaseError: column "person_id" specified more than once
```

Now, I guess my question is, is there any 'proper' ways of doing this or working around this problem?  It would be great if I could just add a switch like `real=False` to the field definition so it wouldn't try and generate the column when building the test DB. However, I don't think that's currently possible.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can. Only it's not called `real`, but `abstract`, and it applies to models (but you should be able to use inheritance to address this).

Your model structure might need a little massaging to correspond to what Django expects, but that should get you started in the right direction.

It's [documented here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes).

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but I don't think this will work for my use.  While they share a `person_id`, that's pretty much all they share in my apparently over-siplified example in my original post.  Sorry for any confusion.